# Getting error "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have few questions in  the below query, the last name line when I uncomment and run the whole query it returns with the error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

And how can I remove Hyphen in postal zip code, below is the code:

Last when I add last name line it gives me this error

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

And below I want to remove  anything after dashes in zip code like example (99297-9925)-- here I want to remove "-9925"-- only few records exist like this:

Comment: I would guess you're passing a negative number to `LEFT`. Can you post some sample data and expected result please? if you're data may, or may not, incldue a `'-'` in the value, make sure you include both examples

Comment: You have both tagged MySQL and SQLServer, 2 entirely separate DBMS with separate language for each. Can you please edit your question and clarify the database associated with this question?

Comment: It may be a data issue, the NameLast could be null or 0, 1 lenght.  So you are trying to use a 0 or 1 in the substring function that is not possible (could be doing -1 or something)  run a query just doing the paramaters of the substring fucntion, like LEN of himRec_Main.NameLast and see if you get any results of 0 or 1 lenght

Comment: Does this return a number? `select count(*) from YourTable where Charindex(',', HimRec_Main.NameLast) = 0` of so, there's that many rows that doesn't contain a comma in the NameLast and that's your issue.

Comment: Using the length of one column (NameLast) with a substring of NameFirst makes **ZERO** sense.

Comment: how about removing numbers after dashes along with dash , please help me .. in the postalcode query above

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the code is correct, but the simplest way to solve this problem with `charindex()` is to affix the searched-for character to the end of the string:

```
FName = ('"' +
         LTRIM(RTRIM(Substring(HimRec_Main.NameFirst, 
                               Charindex(',', HimRec_Main.NameMiddle + ',') + 1, 

                              LEN(HimRec_Main.NameLast)
                              )
                    )
               ) +
         '"'
        ),
LName = ('"' +
         LTRIM(RTRIM(Substring(HimRec_Main.NameLast, 1,
                     Charindex(',', HimRec_Main.NameLast + ',') - 1)
                    )
              ) + 
         '"'
        ) ------- **need help in this one **
```

Comment: how about removing numbers after dashes along with dash , please help me .. in the postalcode query above

Answer (score 1):

You can also split it with **SUBSTRING_INDEX**

```
SET @NAME:="Max,Mustermann";

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@Name, ',', 1);
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@Name, ',', -1);
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [(none)]>     SET @NAME:="Max,Mustermann";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>     SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@Name, ',', 1);
+--------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX(@Name, ',', 1) |
+--------------------------------+
| Max                            |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>     SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@Name, ',', -1);
+---------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX(@Name, ',', -1) |
+---------------------------------+
| Mustermann                      |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: how about removing numbers after dashes along with dash , please help me .. in the postalcode query above

Answer (score 0):

You get the error when `HimRec_Main.NameLast` value doesn't have `','` inside

The below query returns NULL for such values instead of throwing the error:

```
LName ='"'+LTRIM(RTRIM(Substring(HimRec_Main.NameLast,1, NULLIF(Charindex(',', HimRec_Main.NameLast), 0)-1)))
```

Comment: how about  removing numbers after dashes along with dash , please help me .. in the postalcode query above